# Bash - Parse environment variables in bash function

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have a bash function that retrieves environment variables from a `.env` file.

In my `.env` file I have the following variables

```
USER=luis
IMAGE_NAME=application
IMAGE_VERSION=latest
IMAGE_TAG=${USER}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_VERSION}
```

In my bash script I have my env function

```
function dotenv::get() {
  variable=$(grep ^"${1}"= "$(pwd)/.env" | xargs)
  IFS="=" read -ra variable <<< "${variable}"

  echo "${variable[1]}"
}
```

When I execute `dotenv::get IMAGE_TAG`.

Expected result: `luis/application:latest`

Current result: `${USER}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_VERSION}`

I'm aware my function is incomplete, however I'm not sure what are the next steps to achieve my objective.

Comment: `| xargs` what is that `xargs` doing there?

Comment: Is `:` legal in function names? I'd be surprised.

Comment: @KamilCuk Probably to get input from multiple lines onto a single line.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I'm following Google Shell Style Guide
https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html#s7.1-function-names

Comment: Ah, indeed. Seems to be okay in Bash, and allowed in POSIX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file looks like it wants to keep shell-ish syntax. If so, just `source` it:

```
. ./.env
echo "$IMAGE_TAG"

dotenv::get() { 
    . ./.env;
    echo "${!1}"
}
```

If this is not your intention, then implement a whole parser of variables from a file with a `${...}` variable substitution of already set variables.

Comment: Sourcing the file would also set the variables, which is probably not what the user wants. You could (in a child process) source the file and do the `echo`, but then only exported variables would be expanded. I fear to get the functionality the OP asks for, there is no other way than doing an `eval`, with all of its perils (which, of course, would exist if you source the file).

Comment: Sure, so do `dotenv::get() { ( . ./.env; echo "${!1}" ); }`

Comment: This would expand only those **unexported** variables, which are defined in `.env`, but not those which are defined in the process which invokes this function. This may or may not be what the OP wants. See my comment to the question, which talks about this issue.

Comment: I do not understand. No, all variables are available, `.` is executed in current shell. No, subshells executed by `(` `)` share all variables, not only exported ones. And, the `.env` file is self-sufficient - it does not reference any variables that are not set within it itself.

Comment: Does it mean, that if you do a `( ./.env )`, this runs in a child process, but variable expansion performed on the variables in the current process? I thought this applies only to variables which get expanded during parsing the statement (such as `${!1}`, but does this expansion also occur on the sourced statements? After all, the child process does the actual sourcing, isn't it?

Comment: Well, it's trivial to test: `a=1; ( echo $a )`.

Comment: This works of course, because the `$a` is expanded by the calling process. But I made an experiment which goes more along your example: `echo 'A=$b' > x.src;  b=25; B=b; ( . x.src; echo ${!B} )`, and I could verify that it indeed works as advertised. Seems I had a wrong idea about what exactly happens when we source something. In this case, I would suggest that you amend your answer with this subshell version, because I find it the more accurate to what has been asked.

Comment: `because the $a is expanded by the calling process` Wait, you think that `$a` is expanded by the parent shell? No, it isn't. The subshell parses and executes the whole `(.... this stuf ...)`. The parent shell only checks syntax (cause he has to find the matching `)` ). Well, you could do, like: `a=1; ( b=$(echo -e '\x61'); echo ${!b} )` to disprove expanding on parent shell - you have to execute the `echo` to expand `${!b}`.

Comment: If the subshell does the job, how come that it can access the shell variables of the parent? Is this the semantics of the `(....)` construct, i.e. bash cares to create another bash with the same set of variables and functions?

Comment: `Is this the semantics of the (....) construct` Yes, of a "subshell", so also `$(...)` and backticks and pipelines. Let's see [posix shell execution environment](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_12) see `A subshell environment shall be created as a duplicate of the shell environment` stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You are still missing two things: interpreting your variable assignments, and interpreting the content of the variable you query:

```
. $(pwd)/.env  # source the environment file so that variables are assigned

function dotenv::get() {
  variable=$(grep ^"${1}"= "$(pwd)/.env" | xargs)
  IFS="=" read -ra variable <<< "${variable}"

  eval X=${variable[1]}  # interpret the expression containing variables
  echo $X
}

dotenv::get IMAGE_TAG
```

Comment: It's better to do `declare "X=${variable[1]}"`, then `eval` with unquoted expansion.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the indirection operator `${!variablename}`?

Comment: Why do you need to interpret the expression when it was interpreted by `.`?